# Area of a right angled triangle given the dimensions of an inscribed rectangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, rectangles

Is there a way to find the area of the right-angled triangle given the dimensions of the rectangle? The rectangle can fit into the same right-angled triangle in two ways, as shown below:

[image]

Let $a$ = the width of the rectangle, $b$ = the length of the rectangle, $x$ = the base of the right-angled triangle and $y$ = the height of the right-angled triangle. $a$ and $b$ are known quantities as mentioned.

Currently, I'm thinking about similar triangles in the diagram on the left. Using the two smaller right-angled triangles that fit around the rectangle, $(x-a)/a = b/(y-b)$. I also know that the sum of the areas of the mini triangles in the first right-angled triangle is the same as the sum of the areas of the mini triangles in the second right-angled triangle. To express this, I thought about using the labelled lengths for the first right-angled triangle and subtracting the area of the rectangle ($ab$) from the area of the whole right-angled triangle ($\frac{1}{2}xy$) for the second right-angled triangle and equating them.

Expressing this mathematically:
$$\frac{1}{2}a(y-b)+\frac{1}{2}b(x-a)=\frac{1}{2}xy-ab$$

Given that I know what $a$ and $b$ are, surely I can solve for unknowns $x$ and $y$ using simultaneous equations? However, I'm wondering whether I'm missing anything by not explicitly using the fact that the rectangle can fit in two ways?

Comment: Your first equation is wrong. It should be $\frac{x-a}{a} = \frac{y-b}{b}$. To see this, draw a line through the NW and SE corners of the rectangle in the first diagram; it'll be parallel to the hypotenuse. Then draw another line, parallel to the hypotenuse, through the SW corner of the rectangle. Now the "proportional lengths cut off by parallel lines" theorem applies.

Comment: Take that revised equality, and your "expressing this mathematically", and you'll see that there's only one solution. Your "expressing this mathematically" **is** an expression of the fact that the rectangle fits in two ways.

Comment: I still don't get the right answer. For reference, $a=1$ and $b=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. I got an area of 4.05 to 3 s.f. after solving for $x$ and $y$ simultaneously.

Comment: OK. Well, that means either that (a) one of your equations is wrong (b) the "right" answer is wrong, or (c) your algebra is wrong. I'm betting on "c" because when I solved simultaneously and computed $xy/2$, I got an answer a bit larger than $3$. Also, what is "s.f." here? Square feet? Are the lengths given in feet? Because you wrote them as just numbers. Why don't you go ahead and show your work in solving simultaneously, and then perhaps we can be more useful to you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I quoted the wrong answer. I got 3.24 to 3 significant figures (which is what the s.f. stood for). This is however a wrong answer.

Comment: Well...it certainly agrees with my own answer. So perhaps the problem is a case "b" situation. After all, any answer HAS to satisfy those two equations, and only one answer does...

Comment: Perhaps... Anyways, thank you very much for your clarifications

Comment: sirous's observation shows that the problem is in fact wrong in itself: there IS no rectangle that fits into any triangle in the way shown. If there were, then it would have to satisfy the equations you wrote, and could therefore only be the thing you got.

Comment: @JohnHughes I think sirious approach is not rigorous enough. Have a look at my approach, and let me know if you find it OK.

Comment: Given the dimensions $a$ and $b$ of the rectangle, can't you circumscribe a right triangle with $x$ arbitrarily large (and $y$ slightly bigger than $b$), but then the area of the triangle exceeds $xb/2$ .... so NO, you can't find the area of the triangle from the dimensions of the rectangle.

Comment: @Ned, I actually seem to have determined it. Did I wrongly interpret the question?

Comment: @dfnu  I just looked at the first picture and in that case there are arbitrarily large area right triangles that circumscribe the given rectangle ... maybe the second picture forces there to be a unique one of those, in which case the question should be "Given that the same rectangle inscribes into a single right triangle in these two ways, what is the area of the triangle?" which is probably what the OP meant since its trivially impossible with just the first inscribed rectangle.

Comment: I've just been informed that the 'correct' answer is 3.28 to 3 significant figures. I'm really struggling to understand how they got this answer?

Answer (score 1):

We can show that the configuration forces two of the rectangle vertices to coincide, as shown in the figure below, where the two rectangles are $APQR$ and $STUV$.

[image]

Let $\overline{TB}=x$. Then $\overline{SB} = \sqrt{x^2+a^2}$ and similarity $ASV \sim SBT$ yields $\overline{AS} = \frac{bx}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$.

If we now use the similarity $PBQ \sim SBT$ we derive the condition
$$\frac{\overline{TB}}{\overline{TS}} = \frac{\overline{PB}}{\overline{PQ}},$$
i.e.
$$\frac{\overline{TB}}{\overline{TS}} = \frac{\overline{AS}+\overline{SB}-\overline{AP}}{\overline{PQ}},$$
which can be written in terms of the unknown $x$ as
$$\frac{bx}{a} = \frac{bx}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}+\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-a$$
which is equivalent to
$$bx = a\sqrt{x^2+a^2}.\tag{1}\label{1}$$
Recalling that $\overline{AS} = \frac{bx}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$
we get
$$\overline{AS} = \overline{AP} = a.$$
Solving \eqref{1} yields
$$x=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}$$
and therefore
$\overline{SB} = \frac{ab}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}$. Finally, similarity $ABC \sim PQB$ gives
$$\overline{AB} = a+\frac{ab}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}$$
and
$$\overline{AC} = b+\sqrt{b^2-a^2},$$
so that the required area is
$$\boxed{[ABC] = \frac12 \left(a+\frac{ab}{\sqrt{b^2-a^2}}\right)\left(b+\sqrt{b^2-a^2}\right)}.$$

Comment: perfect resolution +1.

Comment: If you let $q = b/a >1 $ be the aspect ratio of the rectangle, and let $r$ be leg ratio of the corresponding triangle (i.e. $r$ is the tangent of angle at $B$), then relationship between them simplifies to $q^2 = r^2+1$, although I only got that by doing hairy algebra on this solution. Maybe there's an easier way to derive it?

Comment: @Ned thanks for the suggestion. I'll have a look into as soon as I can!